# Blade - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

I have a view which displays details about an order but is unable to read the property name of owner.

#### Error Message

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Cuppy_Webshop\resources\views\orders\showOrder.blade.php)

#### Controller

```php
public function show($id){
        $order = Order::with(['owner' => function ($query){
            $query->select('id', 'name');
        }])->where('id', '=', $id)->firstOrFail();

        return view('orders/showOrder', [
            'order' => $order,
        ]);
    }
```

#### Model

```php
public function owner(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'owner');
    }
```

#### Blade

```
<tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td scope="col">{{$order->id}}</td>
                        <td scope="col">{{$order->clip}}</td>
                        <td scope="col">{{$order->engraving}}</td>
                        @if ($order->engraving == 1)
                        <td scope="col">{{$order->front_img}}</td>
                        <td scope="col">{{$order->back_img}}</td>
                        @endif
                        <td scope="col">{{$order->location}}</td>
                        <td scope="col">{{$order->ordered_at}}</td>
                        <td scope="col">{{$order->delivered_at}}</td>
                        <td scope="col">{{$order->status}}</td>
                        <td scope="col">{{$order->cup_id}}</td>
                        <td scope="col">{{$order->owner->name}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

#### JSON

I had the controller return json to see if something was wrong with the formatting or if the property name wasn't being send. Everything seems to be fine:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "clip": 1,
    "engraving": 1,
    "front_img": "Zelda",
    "back_img": "Ultra Smurf",
    "location": "Foodlab",
    "ordered_at": "2019-11-28 15:30:37",
    "delivered_at": null,
    "status": "not payed",
    "cup_id": 1,

    //the owner object
    "owner": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Daan"
    }
}
```

#### What I tried

I tried calling the name of owner as a associative array but that returned null. I dumped `$order` in the view which did show owner having the property name. Googling just gave me results that came down to syntax errors or wrong use of ORM. Had a friend look over my code for syntax errors but found nothing.

Comment: Is owner a model, and do you have the right foreign key bindings in the Order model? It sounds as if the $order->owner function doesn't return a relationship instance, could you post the owner() function?

Comment: @Tim Yes Owner is a Model I'll post the function with the relationship

Answer (score 1):

It's because probably your record does not have owner. 
You can use `whereHas` instead of `with` in your query, or change this line:

```
<td scope="col">{{$order->owner->name}}</td>
```

to this:

```
<td scope="col">{{$order->owner ? $order->owner->name:"no owner"}}</td>
```

You can read more in [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

Comment: A order is required to have a owner. If you look in the JSON code I provided it shows that it is sending an owner object with an id and a name but when I call on it in blade it says that it is a non-object type and can't call the attribute. I'll edit the post to highlight the object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your model should be this way?

```php
public function owner() {
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id_user');
}
```

Comment: The problem is not getting the data as you can see in the JSON code. The problem is accesing the name attribute of the owner attribute in blade. Everything is going fine on the controller side as far as i know.

Comment: I suggested the change on the model because I had a similar problem on one of my applications (the data was in the JSON but I could not access it on the view) and I tried to look the problem on another way. Then I revised the models and that solved the problem. The problem was the relationship in the models.